# VBA Integer Overflow at 70,000

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with 70,000 rows of data and a simple macro that counts the total number of rows:

```
Dim LastRow as Integer    
LastRow = SourceSheet.Cells.Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious, searchorder:=xlByRows).Row
MsgBox (LastRow)
```

This returns an overflow error. Changing LastRow to Long returns the correct value of 70,000.

According to [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx), a VBA integer should be able to hold values between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. My output is well within this range, so why would it fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The website you are looking at is for Visual Studio (.NET) .

VBA Integer is 32,768. You need to use a long.

A VBA Long variable holds whole numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and uses 4 bytes (32 bits) of memory.

```
Dim lLastRow as Long
```

Comment: Gah! Of course I was looking at the wrong page. Thanks for the quick answer. +1

Comment: @DixieFlatline  Just an FYI,  You can also access the last row at anytime by  SourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  and the last column by SourceSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I compared that with the method I was using and I noticed that mine only counts rows with data, and yours also counts rows with formatting.

Comment: @DixieFlatline [Actually `UsedRange` isn't reliable at all for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513)