# Excel VBA Run-time error '424' Object required replacing cell contents with rounded to 2 decimals of current values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace the contents of certain cells with the rounded of the same amounts currently there. The error is on the line where I define the LastRow variable (within the With/End With command). The weird thing is, this code used to work fine a few weeks ago.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    '   Looks up the last row of data and assigns it to one of the variables on columns I and J
    With ActiveWorksheet
        LastRow = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set rng = Range("I2:J" & LastRow)

    '   Replaces current contents of columns I and J with the same value but rounded to 2 decimals
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell = "" Then Exit Sub
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 2)
    Next cell
```

Comment: Also: Qualify the `Range` object with your `ActiveSheet` too when you set `rng`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `ActiveWorksheet`, only [`ActiveSheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet).

Change `ActiveWorksheet` to `ActiveSheet` (and add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module).

<sub>Also note that you should use `Long` instead of `Integer` to avoid a potential `Overflow` error.</sub>

Comment: More on the potential overflow error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436397/vba-integer-overflow-at-70-000/31436414